# Magento - why template doesn't update?

Tags: magento

**Category Hierarchy**

```
Root Catalog
|___ Books
```

I would like to update one particular category and without affect others categories. so I put the following code in Admin->Catalog->Manage Categories->select Book->Custom Design->Custom Layout Update (Magento v1.7)

```
<reference name="category">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>catalog/category/bookview.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

However, after clicking the Book on the top menu, the page is still used the view.phtml (default one). I would expect the bookview.phtml to be used. Is there anyone can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you used the wrong reference. Try using `<reference name="category.products">` instead if you want to update the category page wrapper template or `<reference name="product_list">` if you want to update the products listing itself.

Comment: thanks and it works. I tried to know the convention and avoid making mistakes next time but find nothing on google. Just wondering if there is any tutorials about Custom Layout Update if u know.

Comment: you just have to reference to corespondent XML of the base theme. this time is was app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml and there locate the block which you want to update and use its name.